# Reading TDMS files in python_ how to use tdmsinfo command?

Tags: python, labview

I would like to know what is the content of a tdms file, which is produced by Labview.

Following this [site](http://nptdms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tdmsinfo.html), I write in Python:

```
import numpy as np
from nptdms import TdmsFile
from nptdms import tdms

#read a tdms file
filenameS = "RESULTS.tdms"
tdms_file = TdmsFile(filenameS)

tdmsinfo [--properties] tdms_file
```

I receive the following error:

```
tdmsinfo [--properties] tdms_file
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I do not how to fix it.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Try dropping the [ ]. So: tdmsinfo --properties tdms_file. Note that it is a command line program.

Comment: thank you for your response. I  still get the same error:     tdmsinfo --properties tdms_file
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I think it is a command line program, so that you can't use it in the program. Can you try something like this: channel = tdms_file.object('Group', 'Channel1')
data = channel.data. Otherwise I would suggest you read the manual: https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/nptdms/latest/nptdms.pdf, a lot of code examples in there.

Comment: this  channel = tdms_file.object('Group', 'Channel1') is useful when one knows the path of the object, i first need to know the 'Group' and 'Channel1' names,,,only then i will be able to read their data.

Answer (score 9):

What you are looking for is:

First create a TMDS objet from file:

```
tdms_file = TdmsFile("C:\\Users\\XXXX\\Desktop\\xx Python\\XXXX.tdms")
```

then get the group names with:

```
tdms_groups = tdms_file.groups()
```

after you can figure out which group names you have into the file, just write

```
tdms_groups
```

It will print the following:

['Variables_1', 'Variables_2', 'Variables_3', 'Variables_4', etc..]

With group names now u will be able to get channels with the following:

```
tdms_Variables_1 = tdms_file.group_channels("Variables_1")
```

Next print your channels contain into that group:

```
tdms_Variables_1
```

It will show:

[ TdmsObject with path /'Variables_1'/'Channel_1',  TdmsObject with path /'Variables_1'/'Channel_2', etc..]

At the end get the vectors and its data:

```
MessageData_channel_1 = tdms_file.object('Variables_1', 'Channel_1')
MessageData_data_1 = MessageData_channel_1.data
```

Check your data

```
MessageData_data_1
```

do stuff with your data!
cheers!

Answer (score 1):

To loop over all properties from the root object try this:

```
 #read a tdms file
 filenameS = "RESULTS.tdms"
 tdms_file = TdmsFile(filenameS)
 root_object = tdms_file.object()

 # Iterate over all items in the properties dictionary and print them
 for name, value in root_object.properties.items():
      print("{0}: {1}".format(name, value))
```

That should give you all properties names.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be that tdmsinfo will not work inside a Python script as it is not a python command: it's ["a command line program"](http://nptdms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tdmsinfo.html).

The solution is to either use 'tdmsinfo' from a windows shell, or make a wrapper in python so that it runs the command in a subprocess for you. For instance in Python3 with the subprocess package

```
import subprocess
tdmsfile='my_file.tdms'
# startup info to hide the windows shell
si = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
si.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
#si.wShowWindow = subprocess.SW_HIDE # default
# run tdmsinfo in a subprocess and capture the output in a
a = subprocess.run(['tdmsinfo',tdmsfile],
                   stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                   startupinfo=si).stdout
a = a.decode('utf-8')
print(a)
```

the code above should give you only the channels and groups, but you can also run with the -p flag to include all the TDMS object properties

```
a = subprocess.run(['tdmsinfo','-p',tdmsfile],
                   stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                   startupinfo=si).stdout
```