# DateTime adjustment when reading TDMS files from Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-datetime

I have a TDMS file with a bunch of DateTime values with relevant instrumentation data.
The issue I am having is:

```
TDMS file              >>>> Python Reads  
4/20/2021  12:00:01 AM >>>> 2021-04-20 04:00:00.597573  
4/20/2021  8:00:01 PM  >>>> 2021-04-21 00:00:00.570708
```

This is messing up transfers to the database because it is not accurate.

This is my code:

```
dfscaled = tdmsfile.__getitem__("Data (Scaled)").as_dataframe()  
for index, row in dfscaled.iterrows():
     print(row["Timestamp"])
```

I am using the NPTDMS library. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading TDMS files in python\_ how to use tdmsinfo command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44796977/reading-tdms-files-in-python-how-to-use-tdmsinfo-command)

Comment: @itprorh66 unfortunately no. I dont believe its an issue with the way I am pulling the data. Seems like an issue with how the library reads it. Might have to look for a work-around.

Comment: what does the TDMS file data/time field look like in python?

Comment: @itprorh66 I have shown in the question. Glancing over the questions, I think it is converting it to UTC time in python so maybe if I convert it to EST and not in 24-hour format, that might work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up contacting the author and he was helpful enough to send a response:

> TDMS files internally store times in UTC. You don't say how you're
> getting the values in the "TDMS file" column but I assume this is from
> a program that converts times into your local timezone to display
> them. There is an example of how to convert UTC times from a TDMS file
> into your local timezone in the [documentation](https://nptdms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reading.html#timestamps).
>
> If you are storing these times in a database though, I would strongly
> recommend you store times in UTC rather than your local timezone as
> local times can be ambiguous due to daylight savings changes, and UTC
> is easily understood from anywhere in the world without having to know
> the local timezone where the data originated.

If you still feel like making the change from UTC to EST then this should do it:

```
fmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"
x=pd.to_datetime(row["Timestamp"]).tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('US/Eastern').strftime(fmt)
dtm=pd.to_datetime(x[:-3])
print(dtm)
```